# Query data in SQL Server - C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

How to perform a search having this data in the SQL server

```
?DB203143#F####**
1A4F4N8BX600#####
123H9E3W#9Y1#####
```

when there is special characters `?#**` in the field is equivalent to any characters(a-z) and any numbers(0-9).

```
? = any letters(a-z) or any numbers(0-9)
# = any letters(a-z) or any numbers(0-9)
* = any letters(a-z) or any numbers(0-9)
```

Having this data in the database:

```
ID: ?DB203143#F####**
Model: TestData
```

And when I search for:

```
ID: adb20314431f123456 OR 1DB2031431FFFFFFF OR 0DB2031435F1F05HJ
```

This data must be returned and I can get the model `TestData`

Thank in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure I understand your # and * convention, but assuming you mean # for any number and * for any character, you can use a few metasyntactic variables with SQL Server's LIKE function:

So for example:

```
SELECT
  column1,
  column2
FROM
  testdb
WHERE
  column1 LIKE '?DB203143[0-9]F[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]__';
```

The relevant features here being that you can specify a range of characters inside square brackets to match any character from that range, and you can use an underline to stand in for any single character.  (This will include letters, numbers, punctuation, spaces etc)

If you want to match on any letter OR number, but you want to exclude other stuff like punctuation, you could do it (in a somewhat ugly way) by including every character you want to match inside the square brackets, so something like:

```
[abcdefghjijklmnopqrtuvwxyz0123456789]
```

for each place where you want to match a character.  Admittedly, this gets kind of ugly if you're matching a long sequence like the ones above, for '?DB203143#F####**' it would be along the lines of:

```
LIKE '[abcdefghjijklmnopqrtuvwxyz0123456789]DB203143[abcdefghjijklmnopqrtuvwxyz0123456789]F[abcdefghjijklmnopqrtuvwxyz0123456789][abcdefghjijklmnopqrtuvwxyz0123456789][abcdefghjijklmnopqrtuvwxyz0123456789][abcdefghjijklmnopqrtuvwxyz0123456789][abcdefghjijklmnopqrtuvwxyz0123456789][abcdefghjijklmnopqrtuvwxyz0123456789]'
```

(Assuming here that ? and * and # all equate to 'any number or letter'.)

Comment: And if you meant ANYTHING, use the '%' LIKE 'b%' will return bat and b9 and baby and bill99_032

Comment: # = a-z or 1-9.. same with * ?

Comment: Jen - the way I have written my answer, the [0-9] bits are where we're looking for numbers, and the _ bits will match any character.  If you just wanted letters but not numbers, then I think [a-z] should do the trick.

Comment: These special characters are placed dynamically in the data. It either in the middle, first or last.

Comment: How will I check that there's a special character in the field?

Comment: So, you mean you want to return results when there is actually a '*' or '#' or '?' character in a field?  I think it would just work the same way with those symbols in square brackets:
    LIKE '[*#?]';
Or if you mean how to return results where the field has something other than a letter or number, you can turn a matching pattern in square brackets into its opposite by adding a '^' character like this:
    [^abcdefghijklmnopqrtyvwxyz01234567890]
That will match any character which is NOT a letter or number.

Answer (score 0):

To build on Greg's answer, if you are trying to search all columns and tables for that string, you could do something dynamically with the list of columns. This will give you a list of all the columns in the corresponding table and schema.

```
select
    s.name as SchemaName,
    t.name as TableName,
    c.name as ColumnName
from sys.tables as t
join sys.schemas as s
  on t.schema_id = s.schema_id
join sys.columns as c
  on t.object_id = c.object_id
```

Comment: It is only 1 field in a table